# How to get reset_password working with rails-api app using devise_auth_token gem

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, devise, rails-api

I have made a new rails-api app, integrated devise_auth_token in it. At the moment signup,forgot password is working. But cant get reset password to work.

The confirmation url sent in the mail gives success:false response.

Below is the confirmation url

> http://localhost:3000/auth/password/edit?config=default&redirect_url=foo&reset_password_token=P2a62x8mS9yP9ukeTSZ-

**Here is the server log of reset email**

> Started GET "/auth/password/edit?config=default&redirect_url=foo&reset_password_token=[FILTERED]" for ::1 at 2015-09-24 14:41:21 +0530
>   Processing by DeviseTokenAuth::PasswordsController#edit as */*
>   Parameters: {"config"=>"default", "redirect_url"=>"foo",
>   "reset_password_token"=>"[FILTERED]"} Unpermitted parameters: config,
>   redirect_url   User Load (0.2ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE
>   `users`.`reset_password_token` =
>   '0b3dfdf3a80dce289df8c2cb16c528614b302534264e85e747c4f6b51583da15' 
>   ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1 Completed 404 Not Found in 5ms
>   (Views: 0.3ms | ActiveRecord: 0.2ms)
>
> **Here is the confirmation email which is getting sent on password
>    reset.**
>
> ```
> Started POST "/auth/password?email=user@user.com&redirect_url=foo" for ::1 at 2015-09-24 14:04:05 +0530 Processing by
> ```
>
> DeviseTokenAuth::PasswordsController#create as */*   Parameters:
>   {"email"=>"user@user.com", "redirect_url"=>"foo"} Unpermitted
>   parameter: redirect_url Unpermitted parameter: redirect_url   User
>   Load (66.5ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE (BINARY uid =
>   'user@user.com' AND provider='email')  ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT
>   1   User Load (9.8ms)  SELECT  `users`.* FROM `users` WHERE
>   `users`.`reset_password_token` =
>   '0b3dfdf3a80dce289df8c2cb16c528614b302534264e85e747c4f6b51583da15' 
>   ORDER BY `users`.`id` ASC LIMIT 1    (0.1ms)  BEGIN   SQL (17.7ms) 
>   UPDATE `users` SET `reset_password_token` =
>   '0b3dfdf3a80dce289df8c2cb16c528614b302534264e85e747c4f6b51583da15',
>   `reset_password_sent_at` = '2015-09-24 08:34:05', `updated_at` =
>   '2015-09-24 08:34:05' WHERE `users`.`id` = 6    (63.9ms)  COMMIT
>   Rendered
>   /home/anjan/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.3/gems/devise_token_auth-0.1.34/app/views/devise/mailer/reset_password_instructions.html.erb
>   (16.2ms)
>
> Devise::Mailer#reset_password_instructions: processed outbound mail in
>   424.3ms
>
> Sent mail to user@user.com (64.4ms) Date: Thu, 24 Sep 2015 14:04:06
>   +0530 From: account@qzick.com Reply-To: account@qzick.com To: user@user.com Message-ID:
>   <5603b57e80ae0_1cb520cceb4374ed@anjanbetsy.mail> Subject: Reset
>   password instructions Mime-Version: 1.0 Content-Type: text/html; 
>   charset=UTF-8 Content-Transfer-Encoding: 7bit email: user@user.com
>   provider: email redirect-url: foo client-config: default
>
> Hello user@user.com!
>
> Someone has requested a link to change your password. You can do
>   this through the link below.
>
> Change
>   my password
>
> If you didn't request this, please ignore this email.
>
> Your
>   password won't change until you access the link above and create a new
>   one.
>
> Completed 200 OK in 979ms (Views: 0.6ms | ActiveRecord: 158.1ms)

Guys would appreciate nay help with this.
Even is it any issue the token sent in mail is different form the one generated.? is this suposed to be this way.

Below is my User model.

> {"token"=>"$2a$10$l766Mu/s8IUIHi9r3sz40ODQk2R.YDo283JQ.82Lijb3fjJ5Unqgq", "expiry"=>1444283710}, "H2Cqp2kIt56BYikqXp1HgA"=>{"token"=>"$2a$10$upMCA8ZKLXvq9VjVaz2Vp.sZu7zr2lSTCFrxWnBmg4wC2gQrW9sIW", "expiry"=>1444293849}}, created_at: "2015-09-24 05:55:10", updated_at: "2015-09-24 08:44:09">

Here is my User model file as below

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  # Include default devise modules.
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
          :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable,
          :omniauthable
  include DeviseTokenAuth::Concerns::User
  #Deleted ":confirmable," from above
end
```

**Below is my schema.**

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(version: 20150921074353) do

  create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "provider",               limit: 255,   default: "email", null: false
    t.string   "uid",                    limit: 255,   default: "",      null: false
    t.string   "encrypted_password",     limit: 255,   default: "",      null: false
    t.string   "reset_password_token",   limit: 255
    t.datetime "reset_password_sent_at"
    t.datetime "remember_created_at"
    t.integer  "sign_in_count",          limit: 4,     default: 0,       null: false
    t.datetime "current_sign_in_at"
    t.datetime "last_sign_in_at"
    t.string   "current_sign_in_ip",     limit: 255
    t.string   "last_sign_in_ip",        limit: 255
    t.string   "confirmation_token",     limit: 255
    t.datetime "confirmed_at"
    t.datetime "confirmation_sent_at"
    t.string   "unconfirmed_email",      limit: 255
    t.string   "name",                   limit: 255
    t.string   "nickname",               limit: 255
    t.string   "image",                  limit: 255
    t.string   "email",                  limit: 255
    t.text     "tokens",                 limit: 65535
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
  end

  add_index "users", ["email"], name: "index_users_on_email", using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["reset_password_token"], name: "index_users_on_reset_password_token", unique: true, using: :btree
  add_index "users", ["uid", "provider"], name: "index_users_on_uid_and_provider", unique: true, using: :btree

end
```

My PasswordController file is as below:

```
class PasswordController < ApplicationController
  config.action_controller.action_on_unpermitted_parameters = :log
end
```

Comment: Can you post your User model file, if possible? To check that the devise options specified there are correct....

Comment: @MarcoSandrini Please check I have edited the question and included my User model file at the bottom.

Thanks a lot for your help

Comment: Ok, and now we would need to have a more thorough dump of the User table, cause from what you posted, it seems that the user table does not contain a reset_password_token column...

Comment: @MarcoSandrini Have added my schema.rb file at the bottom Can you please have a look. Thanks again

Comment: Again, everything looks ok. Have you checked this issue? https://github.com/lynndylanhurley/devise_token_auth/issues/160

Comment: @MarcoSandrini I did that still the same failure message pesists.

Have added my PasswordController file at the bottom, can you please have a look at it. Thanks a ton.

Comment: The line you added should go to application.rb, not to the password controller....

Comment: What should my password controller look like can you please help about that how to call this config in my passsword controller as over ride @MarcoSandrini

Comment: Jsut remove the password controller file (you don't need to override anything from it)

Comment: Done all that it still doesnt work @MarcoSandrini

Comment: Then I am afraid I have run out of ideas :(

Comment: @MarcoSandrini Thanks a lot ... appreciate your help and thanks again for your time

Comment: How are you able to get the `redirect_url` in the email sent to user? I am doing the same thing, but still no success: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36262609/redirect-url-is-missing-in-email-instructions-sent-to-the-user-for-password-rese

Answer (score 4):

I faced some crazy difficulties working through this, too. Here's what I had to do go get it working with an AngularJS front end and Rails back:

Override the **PasswordsController** `create`, `update`, `edit`, and `after_resetting_password_path_for`

For the `create` and `update` functions, the primary issue was that I needed it to render a json response, so where it says something like `respond_with resource` I changed to `render json: resource, status: <status>, && return` (you can change resource and status to what you need for your application, same with the render method)

For `edit`, instead of using `after_sending_reset_password_instructions_path_for`, I grabbed the redirect URL from the email and simply do a `redirect_to params[:redirect_url]`

and I changed `after_resetting_password_path_for` to redirect where I want the user to be logged in to.

I also had to change the `reset_password_instructions.html.erb` template. the line which contains **edit_password_url** to this:

```
<p><%= link_to t('.password_change_link'), edit_password_url(@resource, reset_password_token: @token, config: 'default', redirect_url: message['redirect-url'].to_s+'?reset_token='+@token).html_safe %></p>
```

Then in `routes.rb`, I had to let devise know to use my controller:

```
mount_devise_token_auth_for 'User', at: 'auth', controllers: { passwords: 'passwords' }
```

I hope that helps!